# How change position node for level in d3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using using d3js (i new in javascript) for create organization chart, looking this example
[Interactive d3.js tree diagram](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092), but i want to change level position of node. I'm looking for something like:

[image: Tree with Level and Nodes]

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

*I'm Sorry foy my English*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider giving some examples of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [linked sample](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092) is built around D3 tree layout, thus, every node's position is defined by its parent node.

```
const tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

const nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse()
const links = tree.links(nodes);
```

What you want to achieve contradicts the tree layout *by definition*. In other words, you just need to build a layout of your own: calculate **x** and **y** positions for every node according to your guidelines.

When you have an array of nodes `[{x, y, ...}, {x, y, ...}, ...]` and array of links `[{source: node, target: node}, ...]` you can render them exactly like in the sample (the code below `// Update the nodes…` line)

Comment: Thanks for your reply :),
I hope I have understood, considering the nodes of the array, I would add the  level, something like: 
  `{"name": "Son ofA", "parent": "Level 2: B", "level": 2}`  and edit the position of the nodes, on the line
`// Update the nodes…`

Comment: Yes. Just try to render simple tree with positioned nodes and links and then try to figure out how to compute positions by level or parent or something else...

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood your logic and have successfully carried out the functionality.